# Uploading flat files to Azure Storage Account

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-container-service

I was following the instructions from this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python#upload-blobs-to-a-container). I did all the steps for uploading the file to the storage account starting from running this command

```
setx AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING "12334455"
```

Basically, I just copied the code from the Microsoft site for uploading files. But after doing all the requirements as given on the Microsoft site I am still facing some errors.
The code I wrote is

```
import os, uuid
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, ContainerClient, __version__

try:
    print("Azure Blob Storage v" + __version__ + " - Python quickstart sample")
    # local_path = "C:\Users\shang\Desktop\Trial"
    # os.mkdir(local_path)
    #
    # # Create a file in the local data directory to upload and download
    # local_file_name = str(uuid.uuid4()) + ".txt"
    # upload_file_path = os.path.join(local_path, local_file_name)
    #
    # # Write text to the file
    # file = open(upload_file_path, 'w')
    # file.write("Hello, World!")
    # file.close()
    upload_file_path = r"C:\Users\shang\Desktop\Trial\Trial.txt"
    local_file_name = "Trial.txt"
    # Create a blob client using the local file name as the name for the blob
    blob_client = BlobServiceClient.get_blob_client(container="testingnlearning", blob=local_file_name)

    print("\nUploading to Azure Storage as blob:\n\t" + local_file_name)

    # Upload the created file
    with open(upload_file_path, "rb") as data:
        blob_client.upload_blob(data)
        # Quick start code goes here

except Exception as ex:
    print('Exception:')
    print(ex)
```

Now while running the code I am getting the error

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-3a6b42061e89> in <module>
----> 1 blob_client = BlobServiceClient.get_blob_client(container="testingnlearning", blob="Trial.txt")

TypeError: get_blob_client() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Now I don't know of what I am doing wrong. It will be really wonderful if you can tell me on how to upload text files to Azure Storage container.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting the error is because you are not creating an instance of `BlobServiceClient` and using it as static here:

```
blob_client = BlobServiceClient.get_blob_client(container="testingnlearning", blob=local_file_name)
```

What you would want to do is create an instance of `BlobServiceClient` and then use that instance. Something like:

```
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container="testingnlearning", blob=local_file_name)
```

Comment: Thanks @Gaurav. I thought that command "setx AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING "12334455" was sufficient.

Comment: Now just one more question that do I need to run this command if I am already giving the connection string while making blob service client object?
"setx AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING "12334455""

Comment: By using this command, you're essentially setting an environment variable. The benefit of setting the environment variable is that you don't have to explicitly set the connection string in code (just in case you check in the code or share that code with someone else).

Comment: So, it is your call. If you're just trying to learn stuff (i.e. eventually you will discard this code), feel free to keep the connection string in code.